# Select input media device for audio recording using web audio APi

Tags: javascript, audio, web, webrtc, mediastream

Can we set the device from which the audio should be recorded in mediastreamRecorder API using enumerateDevices using Web Audio APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have to first get the specific device's audio stream using `navigator.getUserMedia` and then pass the stream to `mediastreamRecorder`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/648870), Selecting the audio device is the job of the operating system as you can see in the picture below. Thus you would need to construct a plugin that operates at the OS level in order to call into the OS to switch audio devices.

It would be a security risk to just let an app choose what media input device it wanted to use

[image]